# PDF output using django-weasyprint not using css files

Tags: django, weasyprint

I am trying to output PDF using the django-weasyprint package. When opening my detail view, I manage to create the html I wanted. When I want to download it, it looks like messy and doesn`t match the html file.

Here is my views file. How can I add a css file to the DownloadPDF function.

**views.py**

```
class InvoiceView(DetailView):
    # vanilla Django DetailView
    model = Invoice
    template_name = 'accounting/invoices/invoice_pdf.html'

class CustomWeasyTemplateResponse(WeasyTemplateResponse):
    # customized response class to change the default URL fetcher
    def get_url_fetcher(self):
        # disable host and certificate check
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        context.check_hostname = False
        context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        return functools.partial(django_url_fetcher, ssl_context=context)

class InvoicePrintView(WeasyTemplateResponseMixin, InvoiceView):
    # output of MyModelView rendered as PDF with hardcoded CSS
    pdf_stylesheets = [
        settings.STATIC_URL + 'core/static/assets/css/pages/invoice.css',
    ]
    # show pdf in-line (default: True, show download dialog)
    pdf_attachment = False
    # custom response class to configure url-fetcher
    response_class = CustomWeasyTemplateResponse

class InvoiceDownloadView(WeasyTemplateResponseMixin, InvoiceView):

    # suggested filename (is required for attachment/download!)
    pdf_filename = 'invoice.pdf'

class InvoiceImageView(WeasyTemplateResponseMixin, InvoiceView):
    # generate a PNG image instead
    content_type = CONTENT_TYPE_PNG

    # dynamically generate filename
    def get_pdf_filename(self):
        return 'foo-{at}.pdf'.format(
            at=timezone.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M'),
        )
```

Many Thanks,